# C#:inheritance for a child class that does have a property from parent

Tags: c#

I am thinking whether it is possible to have something like this:

```
public class A
{
    public void methodA(){}
}

public class B:A
{

}
```

In such the way that: B does not see the methodA from A, so it is not possible to call:

```
B.methodA()
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask is not possible.

I don't know what you are trying to do. But, if you need to achieve *similar behaviour*, one way to do this is as follows:

```
public class C
{
    // Other methods from class A than MethodA()
}

public class A
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        // Some code
    }
}

public class B : C
{
     // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No.  Doing what you are suggesting would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which 
is one of the main concepts that is core to inheritance.

If "B" does not behave exactly like "A", and an "A" is not replaceable at runtime with a "B", then you should not make `B` subclass `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, mark `MethodA` as private. If you want it to be public then there's no good reason (or way to) allow outside callers to call the method but only block `B`.

If you wanted `B` to be able to 'delete' a method defined by `A`, then you don't want inheritance in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You could override `methodA` in `B` and throw a `NotImplementedException` when it is thrown. But if you're thinking about doing this, you should ask yourself if `B` should really be inheriting from `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! Never do this. You are breaking "is a" paradigm. Use "has a" to implement such behavior. Don't use inheritance. Make B has property of type A.

```
public class A
{
    public void methodA(){}
}

public class B
{
    private A _a
}
```

If you use inheritance B:A. You clearly mention in this way that "B is A" but with some specification. If you see that B don't implement full A interface then there should be no inheritance relation between this types.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line: You can't. That is not what inheritance is about.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in this situation you should rethink *why* you're deriving the class in the first place. If the subclass doesn't contain *all* the methods of the super class, they shouldn't be related in such a way.

Defining B as a subclass of A is akin to saying B will provide all the functionality that A does, plus (whatever else you decide to define). You should re-structure your class hierarchy in this situation.

If you want something like this:

```
public class A
{
    public void sharedFuncA(){}
    public void sharedFuncB(){}
    public void sharedFuncC(){}
    public void methodA(){}
}

public class B:A
{
    public void sharedFuncA(){}
    public void sharedFuncB(){}
    public void sharedFuncC(){}
    public void BOnlyFunction(){}
}
```

You should structure the classes like this instead:

```
public class A : C
{
    public void methodA(){}
}

public class B:C
{
    public void BOnlyFunction();
}

public class C
{
    public void sharedFuncA(){}
    public void sharedFuncB(){}
    public void sharedFuncC(){}
}
```